# Assembly language program termination when user press EXIT

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am having some problem while trying to solve the problem given below.

"Write to write down a program that will take input a single character at a time and in the phase with a gap in the same line it will show the next character that has been already given by the user. There is a condition for stopping the program and that is when the user will press ‘EXIT’ system will terminate"

Actually the last line is not clear to me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since no standard keyboard has an "EXIT" key, it sounds like this is something you need to ask the person who gave you the assignment...

Comment: Presumably it means you have to type `EXIT` (4 characters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, You can use "ESC" key: it is a standard "EXIT" key. ASCII code for "ESC" -  27.